# Installing IR on DB Server by enabling Internet

Tags: sql-server, azure-data-factory

I have an IaaS SQL Server in which internet is disabled.

We plan to set up ADF integration run time on the database server itself rather than creating a new server just for IR.

In order to set up, we need to install .net framework and internet should be available in that VM.

So do we feel that installing .net framework and enabling internet in IaaS SQL Server is a security risk for the database server and we need to go ahead with a new gateway server or is the above idea great for cost saving and less maintenance purpose

Comment: [dup on MS Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/685941/installing-ir-on-db-server-by-enabling-internet.html)

Answer (score 0):

Enabling outbound internet access on a SQL Server is not a security risk, per se.  But using a separate server for the Self-Hosted Integration Runtim (SHIR) is generally recommended over installing it on your SQL Server directly because

1. The SQL Server is isolated from the performance impact of the SHIR
2. A single SHIR can provide access to multiple data sources.
3. You can individually size and scale the SQL Server and the SHIR, and the SHIR doesn't need a SQL Server license.  So it may not cost any more to run them seperately.